# My app will not update the values in the array (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

It will update all the values except for the ones in the array, it won't do that .­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

**This is my update**

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    if (req.body._id) {
        delete req.body._id;
    }
    plan.findById(req.params.id, function(err, plan) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        if (!plan) {
            return res.send(404);
        }
        var updated = _.merge(plan, req.body);
        updated.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            return res.json(200, plan);
        });
    });
};
```

**This is my schema**

```
var ContactSchema = new Schema({
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    total_cost: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    detailed_expenses: {
        transport: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        Hotel: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        Food: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        Attractions: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        }
    },
    holiday_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    transport_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: if `plan` is your mongoose model then do this. `var doc = new plan(req.body)` and then `doc.save(callback)`.

Comment: where do I put this in the code ?

Comment: wherever you want to save the `req.body` which is the document to be saved or any other document you want to save to mongodb using mongoose. in your case replace the following code `var updated = _.merge(plan, req.body);`

Comment: have a look on my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var updated = _.merge(plan, req.body);
```

since `updated` is simple object not the instance of `ContactSchema` hence it wont contain `save` function. So you need to create the instance of `ContactSchema` using `updated` then only you can use `save` function on that. Below is your code with update.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
if (req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
}
plan.findById(req.params.id, function(err, plan) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    }
    if (!plan) {
        return res.send(404);
    }
    var updated = new plan(req.body); //if req.body is document to be saved
    updated.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        return res.json(200, plan);
    });
});
```

};